# Calculate amount to pay over or under budget limit in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, rollup

A customer has a budget of 2700€.

Until the budget is exhausted, the customer does not pay.

The customer makes 3 purchases.

- Purchase No. 1

Amount=1727

Remaining budget= 2700-1727 = 973

Amount to be paid=0. The customer does not have to pay anything because he still has the entire budget available

- Purchase No. 2

Amount=1650

Remaining budget= 2700-(1650+1727) = -677

Amount to be paid=677. The customer only has to pay the difference between the purchase amount and the remaining budget

- Purchase No. 3

Amount=1650

Remaining budget=2700-(1650+1650+1727)=-2327

Amount to be paid=1650. The customer has to pay the full purchase amount because the budget has been used up with purchase 2

Is there a formula in excel that I can apply to calculate 'Amount to be paid' without using IF.

The only way I have found to arrive at the desired result is to use the IF

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: What is wrong with using `IF`?

Comment: I have to take this formula to another environment where I do not have the IF. When it works in Excel without the IF, then it will also work in the other environment where I don't have the IF

Comment: @user3369130 If that is what you are after, then this isn't really an [tag:excel-formula] issue, is it?

Answer (score 0):

As inputs, let's refer to your Budget as `budget`, and to the sum of purchases as `cost`.

As output, let's refer to the amount they need to pay as `payment`.

---

Initially and naïvely, the amount that they need to pay is, therefore, `payment = cost-budget`

However, so long as `cost` is smaller than `budget`, then you want `payment` to remain at zero.

Similarly, if `cost` is smaller than `budget`, then `cost-budget` will be negative — that is to say, it will be an amount *less* than zero!

---

As a result, this means that our final `payment` will be the *larger* value of `0` and `cost-budget`.  In Excel, this can be found with the `MAX` function:

```
=MAX(cost-budget, 0)
```

Or, using the cell references from your existing sheet: either `=MAX($D2-$B2, 0)`, or `=MAX(-$E2, 0)`

| Budget | Cost | Cost-Budget | MAX(Cost-Budget, 0) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2700 | 1727 | *-973* | **0** |
| 2700 | 3377 | 677 | 677 |
| 2700 | 5027 | 2327 | 2327 |

---

Alternatively: you (for some reason) don't have the `MAX` function available, but **do** still have the `ABS` function available, then take advantage of the fact that Negative times Negative is Positive:

```
=(((E2^2)-(E2*ABS(E2)))/2)^0.5
```

| Budget | Cost | Remainder | Remainder^2 | Remainder * ABS(Remainder) | (Remainder^2) - (Remainder * ABS(Remainder)) | = | ÷2 | Square Root |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2700 | 1727 | 973 | 946,729 | 946,729 | (946,729) - (946,729) | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2700 | 3377 | -677 | 444,889 | -444,889 | (444,889) - (-444,889) | 889,778 | 444,889 | 667 |
| 2700 | 5027 | -2,327 | 5,414,929 | -5,414,929 | (5,414,929) - (-5,414,929) | 10,829,858 | 5,414,929 | 2,327 |

Comment: How do I adjust the formula so that for the third row Amount to pay=1650. The customer with the third purchase has to pay the purchase amount (1650) and not 2327

Comment: @user3369130 You need a rollup of how much they have paid, and subtract that.  In Excel, that could just be `SUM(F$1:F1)`   (Note how the second `1` is **not** fixed, so when you drag the formula down into Row 3 it will automatically become `SUM(F$1:F2)`)